# Using GSheets Script to increment value of duplicate by 1

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, increment

I want to check a row for duplicates and if match increment these by 1.

The data I want to manipulate this way is LAT LONG Coordinates.
They originate from an aggregated data acquisition, where users can only insert country and city. Via an Add-On these will get GEO coded.
Problem is, that I need to slightly change the values of duplicate entries, in order to display them on a map. Easiest way (I think) is to increment a LAT or LONG coordinate by 1 if there is already an entry with the same value.

[Data sample & results of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yvjm.png)

Any idea how to do this via Script?

My code, originally intended to delete duplicate rows:

```
function overwriteDuplicates() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Formularantworten 2");
  var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  var hObj={};
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){hObj[e]=i;});//header title to index
  var uA=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(uA.indexOf(vA[i][hObj['Latitude']])==-1) {
      uA.push(vA[i][hObj['Latitude']]);
    }else{
     function increment() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K').getValue() + 1);
}
    }}}
```

Comment: It is always helpful if you share a sample sheet, showing sample data, and the result you would like to see - entered by hand.  See here for how to share:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383.  Secondly, what exactly do you mean by increment a duplicate?  Duplicate values across one row?   Seeing an example may help us understand.

Comment: In the screenshot you provided (1) there's not only increment, but decrement, `835` gets converted to `834`, `835`, `836`, so it is not only increment? (2) longitude is not changed, should it change too?, (3) the duplicate are created in the same row, in different columns (is it always `B:E` which will be duplicated in `H:K`?). Can you clarify all this?

Comment: 1) Only incrementing `835`  to `836` and so on would be sufficent. I just have to generate a new pair of LAT LONG coordinates. Screenshot is a little bit misleading there. 2) LONG cordinates do not have to be chaneged neccessarily to do so. Just changing either one of LAT ot LONG will generate a new pair coordinates. 3) `H:K` shows the target of the data manipulation. I only want to change the duplicates in `B:E` so that the final table looks like `H:K`

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify the latitude whenever duplicate coordinates (latitude and longitude is found).

In this case, you can do the following:

- Get all the values in the sheet, and retrieve the indexes where `Latitude` and `Longitude` are, based on the headers.
- Loop through all rows (excluding headers), and for each row, check whether a previous row contains these coordinates.
- If that's the case (`isDuplicate`), increment the last number in the latitude (after the last `.`), or decrement it if it's close to `999` (I assume there's always 3 digits).
- Store the new latitude in an array after modification.
- Use [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to write the modified latitudes to the sheet.

Below is a possible code snippet to do this (see inline comments for details).

#### Code snippet:

```
function overwriteDuplicates() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Formularantworten 2");
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = values.shift(); // Retrieve first row (headers)
  const latColumn = headers.indexOf("Latitude"); // Latitude column index
  const longColumn = headers.indexOf("Longitude"); // Longitude column index
  let outputLocations = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { // Loop through rows
    const newLocation = { // Store object with current location
      "latitude": values[i][latColumn],
      "longitude": values[i][longColumn]
    }
    let isDuplicate;
    do { // Check if location is duplicate, and increment if necessary
      isDuplicate = outputLocations.some(location => { 
        const sameLatitude = location["latitude"] === newLocation["latitude"];
        const sameLongitude = location["longitude"] === newLocation["longitude"];
        return sameLatitude && sameLongitude;
      });
      if (isDuplicate) newLocation["latitude"] = modifyCoord(newLocation["latitude"]);
    } while (isDuplicate);
    outputLocations.push(newLocation); // Store new location in array
  }
  let outputLatitudes = outputLocations.map(location => [location["latitude"]]); // Retrieve latitudes from array
  sheet.getRange(2, latColumn+1, sheet.getLastRow()-1).setValues(outputLatitudes); // Write updated latitudes to sheet
}
 
function modifyCoord(coordinates) {
  let coordArray = coordinates.split(".");
  let lastCoord = coordArray.pop();
  if (lastCoord > 990) lastCoord--;
  else lastCoord++;
  coordArray.push(lastCoord);
  return coordArray.join(".");
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much lamblichus! Still new, so I cant upvote, but the upvote is in my heart!